# How to enable nginx status page?

Tags: nginx

I need the IP/nginx_status page for my check_nginx_status Nagios plugin. I followed some instructions:

```
nginx -V | grep --color -o http_stub_status #some HttpStubStatusModule verification
```

In nginx.conf, I added:

```
http {
...
server{
  location /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log   off;
    allow MY_IP;
    deny all;
 }
}
...
}
```

After nginx reload, the page should be available.
But, I get "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

I have nginx v1.6.0.

nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    server {

    listen 80;

    location /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log   off;
    #allow 107.170.106.199;
    #deny all;
    }
    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: `nginx -V | grep ...` is useless, because nginx -V writes to stderr. Try to check with `nginx -V 2>&1 | xargs -n1 | grep status`

Comment: It says: "--with-http_stub_status_module"

Comment: May be your request falls to another server block?

Comment: This is the only server block in the file. Could be that the status page is available only for Nginx plus?

Comment: If you have `http_stub_status_module` it should work. Try to remove all `allow` and `deny` directive to make sure they do not matter. Also I don't see any `listen` directive.

Comment: Tried, didn't work. It has the listen 80; directive above location. I removed the server_name since I access through the IP (I tried server name MY_IP; but it reports an error). The IP only (where my app is) is accessible. I added the nginx.conf file above. Btw, thanks for helping.

Comment: I believe your app is somewhere in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*`?

Comment: Yes. I added the location /nginx_status {..} to the app file in sites-enabled. It works now. Don't know why it won't work in nginx.conf. It looks like the files from sites-enabled are not correctly included in the nginx.conf.

Comment: Hi, can you please let me know what fix you have done.

`server {
listen 80 default_server;
location /nginx_status {
stub_status on;
}
}`

but it return 404